# How to reset the migration from Fabric to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

This is my problem: I have an android app that links to Fabric Crashlytics. I have followed steps to migrate to Firebase, but I cannot find the migrated App in my current google account, and I am not sure I have migrated to my current google account. I want to do it again, but the status is marked as "migrated".

My question is:

1) is there any ways I can reset the project status, so that I can re-migrate from Fabric Crashlytics 
to Google Firebase Project?

2) if not, is there any ways I can locate where is my migrated Google Firebase Project? I have used "View app in Firebase Crashlytics", but it ask me to request access.

Comment: I don't think there's a way for you to reset the status. If you're having problems completing the migration, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. It seems unlikely anyone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can unlink your app from Firebase by navigating to Project Settings>Integrations>Fabric. Afterwards, you can go through the migration process once more.